# In Jenkins pipeline getting "error: Missing or incomplete configuration info. Please point to an existing, complete config file"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to implement CICD using Jenkins, While trigger pipeline, i am getting below error. Please advice on this. I am new to this subject. Let me know if more information needed.

I have following Groovy script to achieve:

```
node{
    stage('Git Hub Checkout')
    {
        git credentialsId: 'GitHubCredentials', url: 'https://github.com/account/app'
    }
    stage('Build Docker Image')
    {
        bat 'docker build -t imagename/demo:v2 .'
    }
    stage('Push Docker Image Into Docker Hub')
    {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Docker_Password', variable: 'Docker_Password')]) 
        {
            bat "docker login -u imagename -p ${Docker_Password}"
        }
        bat 'docker push imagename/demo:v2'
    }
    **stage ('Deployment Into Azure')
    {
        bat 'kubectl apply -f deployment-service.yaml'
    }**

}
```

While building "stage ('Deployment Into Azure')" i am getting following error. Please help.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sampleapplication>kubectl apply -f deployment-service.yaml 
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:

1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
ERROR: script returned exit code 1

Note:
     1. C:\Users\username.kube   --> This is the location where kubernetes config file located.

Please refer following reference:
1:

```
C:\Windows\system32>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.5", GitCommit:"20c265fef0741dd71a66480e35bd69f18351daea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:07:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

2:
I have enabled installed docker for windows. I have enabled Kubernetes on that docker for windows plugin.
Refer attached images.

[docker for windows with kubernetes plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpIBN.png)

[jenkins build log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOB83.png)

[kubernetes config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4XbW.png)

[kubectl --kubeconfig="path"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWhZ9.png)

[kubectl-get-pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bv4l.png)

Comment: if your config file is proper for kubernetes please try using : kubectl --kubeconfig="path of file" or else please check the certificate used in kubeconfig file with kubernete cert.

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks for the update, 

1. I tried with kubectl --kubeconfig="path". I am getting attached image result (kubectl --kubeconfig="path"). Issue not yet resolved.

2. Kubectl cert point , you can refer attached image for (kubernetes config file).

Comment: please execute further command like : kubectl --kubeconfig="path of file"  cluster-info. or kubectl --kubeconfig="path of file" get pods.

Comment: @HarshManvar I have executed those two commands and attached the result with name (kubectl-get-pods)

Comment: that's working. you can do one thing now in your pipeline code just add : --kubeconfig="path of file" after each kubectl command. make sure your kubeconfig file available at jenkin server. best practices is to store the config file in credentials.

Comment: working now Jenkins build ?

Comment: @HarshManvar , Just a second ago i tested. It is working fine. Awesome!!!! . You are rocking... Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @harsh Manvar advise, I resolved the above issue.

You can do one thing now in your pipeline code just add : --`kubeconfig="path of file"` after each kubectl command. make sure your kubeconfig file available at jenkin server. best practices is to store the config file in credentials.

**For ex:>>** `kubectl --kubeconfig="C:\Users\username\.kube\config" cluster-info`

```
cluster-info --> Here you can apply your Kubernetes command.
In my case :  bat """kubectl --kubeconfig=C:\\Users\\username\\.kube\\config apply -f deployment-service.yaml"""
```

Note: In Groovy script escape symbol issue purpose i have added `"""`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687751/9521610   BTW, it's better to keep client version in range of one minor version difference from the server. The gap between client v1.18.0 and server v1.15.5 is too big and you may face compatibility issues at some point.