# Running kubectl patch --local fails due to missing config

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that substitutes value in a deployment manifest. I use `kubectl patch --local=true` to update the image. This used to work flawlessly until now. Today the workflow started to fail with a `Missing or incomplete configuration info` error.

I am running `kubectl` with `--local` flag so the config should not be needed. Does anyone know what could be the reason why `kubectl` suddenly started requiring a config? I can't find any useful info in Kubernetes GitHub issues and hours of googling didn't help.

Output of the failed step in GitHub Actions workflow:

```
Run: kubectl patch --local=true -f authserver-deployment.yaml -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"authserver","image":"test.azurecr.io/authserver:20201230-1712-d3a2ae4"}]}}}}' -o yaml > temp.yaml && mv temp.yaml authserver-deployment.yaml

error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:


  1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Output of `kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", 
GitCommit:"ffd68360997854d442e2ad2f40b099f5198b6471", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2020-11-18T13:35:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.0", Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Seem your kube context is not set. check what you get for `kubectl config current-context`

Comment: I got `error: current-context is not set`. Problem I see is that I want to patch the file locally and for that I should not need the context set. Or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sed to replace the string with image

```
  - name: Update manifests with new images
    working-directory: test/cloud
    run: |
      sed -i "s~image:.*$~image: ${{ steps.image_tags.outputs.your_new_tag }}~g" your-deployment.yaml
```

Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I installed kind (it does take longer for the job to finish, but at least it's working and it can be used for e2e tests later).

Added this step:

```
- name: Setup kind
        run: kubectl version
        uses: engineerd/setup-kind@v0.5.0
```

Also use `--dry-run=client` as an option for your kubectl command.

I do realize this is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to set the [config to access kubernetes cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#:%7E:text=The%20kubectl%20command%2Dline%20tool,of%20referring%20to%20configuration%20files.). Even tho you are modifying the file locally, you are still executing `kubectl` command that has to be ran against the cluster.  By default, kubectl looks for a file named config in the `$HOME/.kube` directory.

`error: current-context is not set` indicates that there is no current context set for the cluster and `kubectl` cannot be executed against a cluster. You can create a context for Service Account using [this tutorial](http://docs.shippable.com/deploy/tutorial/create-kubeconfig-for-self-hosted-kubernetes-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

Exporting `KUBERNETES_MASTER` environment variable should do the trick:

```
$ export KUBERNETES_MASTER=localhost:8081  # 8081 port, just to ensure it works 

$ kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.8", GitCommit:"9f2892aab98fe339f3bd70e3c470144299398ace", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate
:"2020-08-13T16:12:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8081 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

# Notice the port 8081 in the error message ^^^^^^
```

Now patch also should work as always:

```
$ kubectl patch --local=true -f testnode.yaml -p '{"metadata":{"managedFields":[]}}'    # to get the file content use  -o yaml 
node/k8s-w1 patched
```

Alternatively, you can update `kubectl` to a later version. (v1.18.8 works fine even without the trick)

**Explanation section:**

The change is likely to be introduced by **[PR #86173 stop defaulting kubeconfig to http://localhost:8080](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/86173)**

The change was reverted in **[Revert "stop defaulting kubeconfig to http://localhost:8080" #90243](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/90243)** for the later **18.x** versions, see the issue **[kubectl --local requires a valid kubeconfig file #90074](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90074)** for the details